# express 3.0 bodyParser not working properly

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I am using the latest version of express no. 3. I have read the docs and I did exactly as was written but it is still not working as it is supposed to.  I get a file in my upload dir after submitting, but then everything stops and the callback function from app.post doesn't fire. The code:

HTML-JADE:

```
form(action="/upload", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
  input(type="file", name="image")
  input(type='submit', value='submit')
```

App.js:

```
var express = require('express')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , mongo = require('mongodb')
  , Server = mongo.Server
  , Db = mongo.Db
  , routes = require('./routes')
    
var  app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir:'./upload'}));
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
  app.use(express.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(require('stylus').middleware(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.files.image) // this doesn't fire at all - no matter what i write here 
  res.send(200) //doesn't run also
});
```

Comment: more modern versions require `var bodyparser = require('body-parser'); app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));` and, of course, one has to first `npm install body-parser`

Answer (score 2):

You need to return a response after reading the data. Without returning a response, express has no idea of when your response is finished and node will not close the connection to the client.

try this:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.files.image);

  req.on('data', function(raw) {
    console.log('received data');
  });

  req.on('end', function() {
    console.log('end');
    res.send(200);
  });
}
```

Comment: it looks like after receiving file it stops - doesn't execute function in app.post at all.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It would make sense that the upload has to be read completely first and that the response code should not be sent until firefox has sent all the data.

Comment: does hit your console.log statement?

Comment: still the same - nothing happens

Comment: after submit browser is looking for somenthing and send status is "pending"

Comment: when i use chrome postmen and send post to /upload response is working  so it seems like express problem with multipart/data

Comment: try commenting out the bodyparser middleware

Comment: i put simplified version on github - https://github.com/deeveeloop/files if anyone want to check what is wrong

Comment: I tried your github version and couldn't reproduce it on chrome or firefox on mac so it might be either browser related or node version related. btw, it would be nice to get an explanation for the downvote for whoever downvoted both answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try sending a simple response to the user.

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.files.image);
  res.write('File Uploaded !!');
  res.end();
}
```

**Update**

You should try changing the format to

```
app.post('/upload', function(err,req,res,next){
//Check for errors then handle it
}
```

Can't tell much until I know what errors you are getting, since file is being uploaded to upload dir `bodyParser` is working fine. Maybe your route is being handled by another function, or not handled at all. `app.router` is code that calls the callback .

When you do `app.get('/upload', function(req, res) { ... });` it is the router that actually invokes the callback function to process the request. Can you confirm if you can do `app.get('/upload',...);` the html-jade file succesfully. If not then there is a problem in your routes.

Comment: it uploads the file but then do nothing - no colsole log no write nothing - browser is busy after submit - like searching for something . When i use postman and send simple post req - it works but with file anbd form no

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a hotline service for debugging anyone's code. I would ask the downvoters to provide a solution themselves before downvoting or at least explain their vote. Try not judging others before attempting to solve it yourself. This does not help the OP or anyone who visits this page

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found solution - that was because i used node 0.9.6 -pre. After change to 0.8.21 everything works fine.

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Whats the problem in using node 0.9.6?? I am having almost the same problem.

Comment: Thankx a ton buddy. After spending 2 days in debugging this issue and searching for problems, I found this thread. Now, I moved to node v0.10.16